# SQL Agrupamiento en una consulta

Tags: sql, select, subconsultas

Buen día chicos mi duda es la siguiente:

Necesito llegar a la siguiente tabla:

[image: Resultado Final]

Les explico como está formado.

Necesito que en la consulta me regrese tal cuál la información que viene en la imagen.

- **Para lo trabajado** existen ciertos idstatus en la tabla del universo en la que los id, deben de ser: 14,15,8,9,10,11,12
- **Y para el universo** los id de status deben ser solamente los  1.
- **Para la Diferencia** es la resta del Universo menos lo trabajado.

Tengo las consultas necesarias para trabajarlo, pero no sé como mandarlo en una sola consulta.

```
**Consulta para lo trabajado**


(SELECT ent.ef,ent.id_ef, SUM(mul.imp) as ImporteHistorico, COUNT(mul.imp) as MultasHistoricas
FROM t_cont reg, t_cpto mul, t_status est, cat_ef ent
WHERE reg.idcliente = mul.Id_cont
AND mul.id_cpto = est.id_cpto
AND ent.id_ef = reg.id_ef
AND est.cve_status in (14,15,8,9,10,11,12)
GROUP BY ent.ef, ent.id_ef
) 

ef  id_ef   ImporteHistorico    MultasHistoricas
Equipo1 9   100000.00   1
Equipo2 30  200000.00   2
Equipo3 31  1971000.00  7
Equipo4 32  38000.00    5


**Consulta para el Universo**

(SELECT ent.ef,ent.id_ef, SUM(mul.imp) as ImporteTrabajado, COUNT(mul.imp) as MultasTrabajadas
FROM t_cont reg, t_cpto mul, t_status est, cat_ef ent
WHERE reg.idcliente = mul.Id_cont
AND mul.id_cpto = est.id_cpto
AND ent.id_ef = reg.id_ef
AND est.cve_status in (1)
GROUP BY ent.ef, ent.id_ef
)

ef  id_ef   ImporteTrabajado    MultasTrabajadas
Equipo1 9   300000.00   2
Equipo2 30  300000.00   4
Equipo3 31  6572000.00  21
Equipo4 32  165000.00   25
```

Realmente mi pregunta es esa, como puedo poner todo esto junto, es decir lo siguiente:

```
    (SELECT ent.ef,ent.id_ef, SUM(mul.imp) as ImporteHistorico, COUNT(mul.imp) as MultasHistoricas,

    --AQUI
(SELECT ent.ef,ent.id_ef, SUM(mul.imp) as ImporteTrabajado, COUNT(mul.imp) as MultasTrabajadas
    FROM t_cont reg, t_cpto mul, t_status est, cat_ef ent
    WHERE reg.idcliente = mul.Id_cont
    AND mul.id_cpto = est.id_cpto
    AND ent.id_ef = reg.id_ef
    AND est.cve_status in (1)
    GROUP BY ent.ef, ent.id_ef
    )-- Termina
    FROM t_cont reg, t_cpto mul, t_status est, cat_ef ent
    WHERE reg.idcliente = mul.Id_cont
    AND mul.id_cpto = est.id_cpto
    AND ent.id_ef = reg.id_ef
    AND est.cve_status in (14,15,8,9,10,11,12)
    GROUP BY ent.ef, ent.id_ef
    )
```

Pero me manda el siguiente error:

```
Sólo se puede especificar una expresión en la lista de selección cuando la subconsulta no se especifica con EXISTS.
```

¿Alguien pudiera apoyarme, en como lo pudiera hacer?

**De antemano muchas gracias.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas tener un agregado condicional para poder tener varias columnas.

```
SELECT ent.ef,
    ent.id_ef, 
    SUM( CASE WHEN est.cve_status in (1) THEN mul.imp ELSE 0 END) as ImporteHistoricoUniverso, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN est.cve_status in (1) THEN mul.imp ELSE NULL END) as MultasHistoricasUniverso, 
    SUM( CASE WHEN est.cve_status in (14,15,8,9,10,11,12) THEN mul.imp ELSE 0 END) as ImporteHistoricoTrabajado, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN est.cve_status in (14,15,8,9,10,11,12) THEN mul.imp ELSE NULL END) as MultasHistoricasTrabajado
FROM t_cont   reg
JOIN t_cpto   mul ON reg.idcliente = mul.Id_cont
JOIN t_status est ON mul.id_cpto = est.id_cpto
JOIN cat_ef   ent ON ent.id_ef = reg.id_ef
WHERE est.cve_status in (1,14,15,8,9,10,11,12) --Tenemos todos los posibles valores
GROUP BY ent.ef, ent.id_ef;
```

También podrías tener la consulta en un CTE o subconsulta para obtener el tercer grupo de columnas.

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT ent.ef,
        ent.id_ef, 
        SUM( CASE WHEN est.cve_status in (1) THEN mul.imp ELSE 0 END) as ImporteHistoricoUniverso, 
        COUNT(CASE WHEN est.cve_status in (1) THEN mul.imp ELSE NULL END) as MultasHistoricasUniverso, 
        SUM( CASE WHEN est.cve_status in (14,15,8,9,10,11,12) THEN mul.imp ELSE 0 END) as ImporteHistoricoTrabajado, 
        COUNT(CASE WHEN est.cve_status in (14,15,8,9,10,11,12) THEN mul.imp ELSE NULL END) as MultasHistoricasTrabajado
    FROM t_cont   reg
    JOIN t_cpto   mul ON reg.idcliente = mul.Id_cont
    JOIN t_status est ON mul.id_cpto = est.id_cpto
    JOIN cat_ef   ent ON ent.id_ef = reg.id_ef
    WHERE est.cve_status in (1,14,15,8,9,10,11,12) --Tenemos todos los posibles valores
    GROUP BY ent.ef, ent.id_ef
)
SELECT ef,
    id_ef, 
    ImporteHistoricoUniverso, 
    MultasHistoricasUniverso, 
    ImporteHistoricoTrabajado, 
    MultasHistoricasTrabajado,
    ImporteHistoricoUniverso - ImporteHistoricoTrabajado AS DiferenciaImporteHistorico, 
    MultasHistoricasUniverso - MultasHistoricasTrabajado AS DiferenciaMultasHistoricas
FROM CTE;
```

Comment: Agradezco tu respuesta tan pronta Luis. Me sirvió de maravilla tus respuestas.
Buen día.

Comment: Espero que entiendas la lógica que se presenta y si no es así, por favor dime que puedo explicar de mejor manera.

Comment: Luis Cazares. Buen día. Estaba analizando el query y hay una parte que aun no entiendo muy bien:

SUM( CASE WHEN est.cve_status in (1) THEN mul.imp ELSE 0 END) as ImporteHistoricoUniverso, 
        COUNT(CASE WHEN est.cve_status in (1) THEN mul.imp ELSE NULL END) as MultasHistoricasUniverso, 

En especifico el else NULL y el else 0

Comment: En la suma uso un cero para que no queden valores nulos en caso de no haber datos. En el COUNT() uso NULL para que la función omita esa fila y, por lo tanto, no la cuente. En este último caso, la función COUNT() siempre regresará un valor aunque no haya filas que contar.